# 403.4 won't redirect in IE7

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-6, ssl-certificate, internet-explorer

I have a secured folder that requires SSL. I have set it up in IIS(6) to require SSL. We don't want the visitors to be greeted with the "must be secure connection" error, so I have modified the 403.4 error page to contain the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectToHttps()    {

    var httpURL = window.location.hostname+window.location.pathname;

    var httpsURL = "https://" + httpURL ;

    window.location = httpsURL ;

}
redirectToHttps();
</script>
```

And this solution works great for every browser, but IE7. On any other browser, if you type in http://www.mysite.com/securedfolder it will automatically redirect you to https://www.mysite.com/securedfolder with no message or anything (the intended action). But in Internet Explorer 7 ONLY it will bring up a page that says

```
The website declined to show this webpage
Most Likely Causes:
This website requires you to log in
```

This is something we don't want of course. I have verified that javascript is enabled, and the security settings have no effect, even when I set them to the lowest level I get the same error.

I'm wondering, has anyone else seen this before?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that IE's "Friendly Error Message" feature is replacing your error page with one it thinks is easier for people to understand.  According to [this kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807), the "friendly error message" is not used when the server response is large enough, and suggests padding your custom error page with spaces until it is.

Answer (score 0):

I never experience it before, but, i wonder why you use javascript to do it ? Ever tried with the

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.the-domain-you-want-to-redirect-to.com"> ?
```

The way I deal with this problem was easy, since I use ASP.NET.
You make an abstract page class or HttpModule (entire web app) that check if `(!Request.IsSecure)` ... redirect with a 301 to secure page.

This nice thing about doing it server-side is that it will work without javascript. I'm pretty sure you can do the same in any language (Java, PHP, ruby even c++ if you're old school).